# How can I show colored hostname on the prompt in Powerline-Plain [Bash-it] theme?

Tags: bash, powerline, bash-it

I would like to show hostname at the beginning of the prompt in **Powerline-Plain [Bash-it]** theme.

Something like: **MYHOSTNAME root /var/www**

This is the default looks: 
[image: root /var/www]

and I'd like to assign to it a different random and fixed color for each different hostname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just overwrite the `POWERLINE_PROMPT` variable in your `.bashrc` file and add `hostname` like this:

```
export POWERLINE_PROMPT=${POWERLINE_PROMPT:="hostname user_info scm python_venv ruby node cwd"}
```

Answer (score 0):

**\h** is what you need to display the hostname in your bash prompt. In order for it to appear in a certain color, you need to wrap that part in the color codes you like. Like this you can define the color RED when you are root for example.

```
USERCOLOR='\[\e[1m\]'
NORMCOLOR='\[\e[m\]'
# If I am root, set the prompt to bright red
if [ ${UID} -eq 0 ]; then USERCOLOR='\[\e[1;31;7;47m\]'; fi
PS1="[$USERCOLOR\h$NORMCOLOR]\\n\#-\\$> "
```

Answer (score -1):

As outlined in the [Bash-it Powerline documentation](https://github.com/Bash-it/bash-it/tree/master/themes/powerline#segment-order), you can use the `hostname` name to add the hostname to your Powerline prompt:

> The contents of the prompt can be "reordered", all the "segments" (every piece of information) can take any place. The currently available segments are:
>
> - `aws_profile` - Show the current value of the AWS_PROFILE environment variable
> - `battery` - Battery information (you'll need to enable the battery plugin)
> - `clock` - Current time in HH:MM:SS format
> - `cwd` - Current working directory including full folder hierarchy (c.f. wd)
> - `hostname` - Host name of machine
> - `in_vim` - Show identifier if running in :terminal from vim
> - `k8s_context` - Show current kubernetes context
> - `last_status` - Exit status of last run command
> - `python_venv` - Python virtual environment information (virtualenv, venv and conda supported)
> - `ruby` - Current ruby version if using rvm
> - `node` - Current node version (only nvm is supported)
> - `scm` - Version control information, git
> - `user_info` - Current user
> - `wd` - Working directory, like cwd but doesn't show the full folder hierarchy, only the directory you're currently in.
> - `shlvl` - Show the current shell level (based on SHLVL environment variable), but only if you are not in root shell
> - `dirstack` - Show the current dirstack level (based on DIRSTACK environment variable), but only if the stack is not empty
> - `history_number` - Show current history number
> - `command_number` - Show current command number
>
> A variable can be defined to set the order of the prompt segments:
>
> `POWERLINE_PROMPT="user_info scm python_venv ruby cwd"`

Based on this, you can add the `hostname` segment to the `POWERLINE_PROMPT` variable (e.g. in your Bash profile):

```
export POWERLINE_PROMPT="hostname user_info scm python_venv ruby cwd"
```

This will add the hostname as the first entry in the prompt.

There currently is no functionality in Bash-it to assign a random colour to the prompt segments.